# Nested movieClips not detecting mouse events in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, movieclip

I have some nested movieClips. I've got an event listener on the parent listening for a mouse click. Problem is, the listener never picks up the click.

Code:

```
    var movieClipStack:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

    for each (var ol:OwnedLayerable in owned_layerables)
    {
        var mc:MovieClip = ol.layerable.mc;
        movieClipStack.buttonMode = true;
        movieClipStack.addChild(mc);
    }

    movieClipStack.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStackClicked);

    private function onStackClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
```

On movieClipStack, I can see that mouseEnabled = true. In addition, buttonMode = true works exactly like it's supposed to. But onStackClicked never happens - movieClipStack just isn't detecting any sort of mouse event.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A couple ideas...

First check to make sure that `movieClipStack.mouseEnabled == true`, just to make sure that you aren't inadvertently disabling messages from the mouse to your object.

Then I'd take a look at what `hitArea` you have set for `movieClipStack` with `trace( movieClipStack.hitArea );`. Check its `width` and `height` values to see if it's roughly what you would expect the width and height of `movieClipStack` to be.

Then I'd experiment with creating a simple rectangular sprite and setting it as the `hitArea` for `movieClipStack`.

I hope that works. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a little known property called "mouseChildren" that you must set for the content elements of your mouse-listening movieclip.

If you do not remove those other elements from the event stream, they tend to eclipse events in a not-so-predictable way.

So, you would assign it like this:

```
 parentMovieClip.mouseChildren = false;// turns off all internal mouse-listening clips
```

If you were putting this inside the MovieClip, or inside a class definition, I usually just do it this way:

```
 mouseChildren = false;
```

Also, here is an Adobe article explaining the whole thing:
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html

Hope this helps! It took me HOOOOOOOURS to finally unearth this one.